# "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature." when using "get" keyword in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a provider configurationService that has this function with `get` keyword:

```
get getServerContextPath(): string {
    return this.config.serverContextPath;
}
```

When I'm using this function in a component like this:

```
const contextPath = this.configurationService.getServerContextPath();
```

I'm getting an error:

> [ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
>   Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures.

However if I remove the get keyword, I don't get any errors:

```
getServerContextPath(): string {
    return this.config.serverContextPath;
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: If you are using ``get/set`` the ``()`` is redundant while executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, your get a `property` so you have to call it as

```
const contextPath = this.configurationService.getServerContextPath
```

In the second case it's a `method` (function) of a class so you can call it as

```
const contextPath = this.configurationService.getServerContextPath()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
const contextPath = this.configurationService.getServerContextPath;
```